# PHP Regex? - display x no of characters after y

Tags: php

I am trying to display *9 characters after a series of characters* within a body of text.

**Examples:**

```
var=abcdefghi12345678

12345abcdefghi678910

someTEXTabcdefghiVAR1
```

in each example above I would like to display `abcdefghi` (9 characters)

I am trying to create a **regex** that I can change based on the preceding characters. 
I will always know the preceding characters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a regular expression if you know the preceding characters.

```
<?php

// We know the preceding characters.
$preceding = "someTEXT";

// The actual string.
$string = "someTEXTabcdefghiVAR1";

// The next nine characters after the preceding string.
echo mb_substr($string, mb_strlen($preceding), 9);

// OUTPUT: "abcdefghi"
```